# How add product with pick_list modifier to cart

Tags: bigcommerce

What is the appropriate syntax to add a sku with picklist modifiers to cart?

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/storefront-cart-api/cart/addcartlineitem

Assuming this is my product

`GET https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/:store-hash/v3/catalog/products?include=modifiers,variants&id:in=237`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 237,
            "name": "Awesome Bundle Sku",
            "type": "physical",
            "sku": "BUNDLE1",
            "description": "",
            "weight": 1,
            "width": 1,
            "depth": 1,
            "height": 1,
            "price": 99,
            "cost_price": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "sale_price": 0,
            "map_price": 0,
            "tax_class_id": 0,
            "product_tax_code": "",
            "calculated_price": 99,
            "categories": [
                50
            ],
            "brand_id": 0,
            "option_set_id": 25,
            "option_set_display": "right",
            "inventory_level": 0,
            "inventory_warning_level": 0,
            "inventory_tracking": "none",
            "reviews_rating_sum": 0,
            "reviews_count": 0,
            "total_sold": 0,
            "fixed_cost_shipping_price": 0,
            "is_free_shipping": false,
            "is_visible": false,
            "is_featured": false,
            "related_products": [
                -1
            ],
            "warranty": "",
            "bin_picking_number": "",
            "layout_file": "product.html",
            "upc": "",
            "mpn": "",
            "gtin": "",
            "search_keywords": "",
            "availability": "available",
            "availability_description": "",
            "gift_wrapping_options_type": "any",
            "gift_wrapping_options_list": [],
            "sort_order": 500,
            "condition": "New",
            "is_condition_shown": false,
            "order_quantity_minimum": 0,
            "order_quantity_maximum": 0,
            "page_title": "",
            "meta_keywords": [],
            "meta_description": "",
            "date_created": "2019-05-29T19:16:08+00:00",
            "date_modified": "2019-08-24T19:28:45+00:00",
            "view_count": 0,
            "preorder_release_date": null,
            "preorder_message": "",
            "is_preorder_only": false,
            "is_price_hidden": false,
            "price_hidden_label": "",
            "custom_url": {
                "url": "/bundle1/",
                "is_customized": false
            },
            "base_variant_id": 202,
            "open_graph_type": "product",
            "open_graph_title": "",
            "open_graph_description": "",
            "open_graph_use_meta_description": true,
            "open_graph_use_product_name": true,
            "open_graph_use_image": true,
            "variants": [
                {
                    "id": 202,
                    "product_id": 237,
                    "sku": "BUNDLE1",
                    "sku_id": null,
                    "price": 99,
                    "calculated_price": 99,
                    "sale_price": 0,
                    "retail_price": 0,
                    "map_price": 0,
                    "weight": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "depth": 1,
                    "is_free_shipping": false,
                    "fixed_cost_shipping_price": 0,
                    "calculated_weight": 1,
                    "purchasing_disabled": false,
                    "purchasing_disabled_message": "",
                    "image_url": "",
                    "cost_price": 0,
                    "upc": "",
                    "mpn": "",
                    "gtin": "",
                    "inventory_level": 0,
                    "inventory_warning_level": 0,
                    "bin_picking_number": "",
                    "option_values": []
                }
            ],
            "modifiers": [
                {
                    "id": 140,
                    "product_id": 237,
                    "name": "53701567688198-237",
                    "display_name": "5370",
                    "type": "product_list",
                    "required": true,
                    "sort_order": 1,
                    "config": {
                        "product_list_adjusts_inventory": false,
                        "product_list_adjusts_pricing": false,
                        "product_list_shipping_calc": "none"
                    },
                    "option_values": [
                        {
                            "id": 127,
                            "option_id": 140,
                            "label": "COMPONENT1",
                            "sort_order": 0,
                            "value_data": {
                                "product_id": 136
                            },
                            "is_default": true,
                            "adjusters": {
                                "price": null,
                                "weight": null,
                                "image_url": "",
                                "purchasing_disabled": {
                                    "status": false,
                                    "message": ""
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "total": 1,
            "count": 1,
            "per_page": 250,
            "current_page": 1,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "links": {
                "current": "?limit=250&include=modifiers%2Cvariants&id%3Ain=237&page=1"
            },
            "too_many": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`POST https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/:store-hash/v3/carts/:cart-id/items`

```
{
    "line_items": [
        {
            "product_id": 237,
            "quantity": 1,
            "option_selections": [
                {
                    "option_id": 140,
                    "option_value": 127
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```